# Using Image Links in Wordpress Navigation Menus Instead Of Text Links

Tags: menus, navigation

Does wordpress support the capability to use images in the navigation menus instead of text links? I searched for this capability and found a site that shows how to include images in the menu through css editing:

http://vanweerd.com/how-to-replace-text-links-with-icon-links-in-wp-3-navigation-menus/

If wordpress does not support the ability to easily add an image in as a linkable object in the nav menu, is there a plugin that can do this? I would like to have the ability to add and remove images to a navigation menu without having to edit css.

Comment: What's wrong with the CSS method? I don't think you'll find a plugin that makes it any more simple to be honest(i don't mind being wrong though).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

## 1. Misuse the description

Go to `wp-admin/nav-menus.php`, open the options and enable the description field. Write the image paths into the description field and use a [custom walker](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output) to modify the output of [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

## 2. Use a custom post type

I have written a custom post type **Navigation** (hierarchical) similar to *pages* with a normal editor box, a title field and a meta box for URIs. The client writes his HTML and my code creates a navigation from these entries.

You can add any HTML, images, forms and videos. Really easy to use, but it requires a lot of code.

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain your context a little?

I also think CSS is very fitting solutions to this. Partly because it makes sense for content/presentation balance, partly because custom menus are quite complex to figure out and I usually stay away form their internals.

I use CSS with set of icons at my blog, so I just add a custom class to menu item and CSS styles it accordingly. See [Rarst.net](http://www.rarst.net/).

Comment: Yes, I would like to make the image setting as configurable as possible by the blogger who doesn't necessarily know CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I know of:

- [Blogroll Links Favicons](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blogroll-links-favicons/)
- [BlogWell's Simple Image Link
  Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-image-link/)

maybe one of them will suite your needs.. take a look

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem, aside from not enough information.
You can just use an a-tag with a class, link it to whereever and then add a background-image via CSS. You can reuse the classes for identical images or use different classes for different images.